# How to upload an Arduino source code to a Lilypad Arduino?

Tags: sockets, arduino

I bought a `Lilypad Arduino`, for which an FTDI socket is required to connect to my PC. The first socket I tried on didn't power up the Arduino, because of some hardware damage. Thus, I got another socket, but with 4 female pins (Vcc, Gnd, TX, RX), unlike the previous one that had 6 male pins. Let's call the second socket as X. With X, the `Lilypad` is getting powered up through USB cable. Then, when I tried to upload my source code the first time, it started working.
But when I uploaded it some time later, an **error called 'programmer is not responding'** occurs always, which I'm unable to resolve.
*What should I do?*

Answer (score 0):

To program an Arduino (and Arduino-compatibles), you need an FTDI adapter that has an RTS pin, as well as the Vcc, Gnd, TX, and RX pins.

The RTS pin connected to the reset circuit on the Arduino, putting the bootloader into programming mode for a few seconds.

You may be able to get it to work by resetting the Lilypad with it's reset button, then upload your sketch within a few seconds after the reset. Alternatively, or for the least hassle, get an FTDI adapter with all the needed signals. I recommend Adafruit's [FTDI Friend](https://www.adafruit.com/products/284).